# Why rapidjson has error and said json file is NULL while it has data?

Tags: json

Im trying to run a project (https://github.com/abignoli/EdgeGraph3D), but when im running the command i have this error:

**geo@geo-X570-GAMING-X:~/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/build$** ./EdgeGraph3D /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/images/ /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/edges/ /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/work/ input_sfm_data.json /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/output.json

## EdgeGraph3D

Input SfM data: input_sfm_data.json

Input images: /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/images/

Input edges: /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/edges/

Working folder: /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/work/

Output: /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/example/dtu006/output.json

Computing on 16 threads

JsonParseException--> the json file  is NULL

EdgeGraph3D: /home/geo/Github_Projects/EdgeGraph3D/external/rapidjson/document.h:1064: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::ConstMemberIterator rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::MemberEnd() const [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::ConstMemberIterator = rapidjson::GenericMemberIterator<true, rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<> >]: Assertion `IsObject()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Im not sure, because im new, its something wrong with rapidjson parse? Any help would be aprreciated.

Thanks in advance guys!

**EDIT**

[Part of Json File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhkTH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and i forgot to post it. The problem, in my situation, was that some paths were not right.